# No "waiting for review" for comment flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, flag-history

Let me explain using screenshot and Free Hand Red Circles and Arrows:

> [image]

As comment flags are now fully showing in the summary, I would expect the same behavior by showing how many are still active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) this has been pushed in the latest build.  There will now be a category for comments waiting for review.

Comment: So Oded got a Voice now? ;-)